# Wix import new products via CSV file

Tags: csv, import, velo

Good day,

I've tried to import new products to my WIX website via a CSV file that I downloaded, but when I add a new product to this file I need to insert the handleId code, how do I get this code if the new product?

Answer (score 0):

I was just recently wondering this as well and upon having a look at the wix-import-template, I noticed that all handleIDs of the products were simply Product_1, Product_2 and so on and so forth... (all varients of a product have to have the exact same handle as the product they are a part of so:
Product_1,Product,otherAttributes...
Product_2,Product,otherAttributes...
Product_2,Variant,otherAttributes...
etc...
Therefore, if you are using code, you can simply use a for-loop and insert the i-value into the string (if you only have products and no variants, will have to adjust it otherwise)

Wish you a nice day and I hope this helps!
Greetings, Thomas